# Hyperterminal for RPi: data transfer from device to RPi

Tags: pi-2, rpi.gpio

I have a strength meter device (look at the photo), and I want to transfer data from it to Rpi2 (Raspbian OS). Transferring data to Windows easily accomplished through the Hyperterminal program. Device connect with RPi via the RS-232 port. I can not find Hyperterminal analogue for RPi. Tell me please, is there such a program?  Data transfer process is started by Print key on the device.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a program like GTKTerm on Raspbian as Hyperterminal alternative.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtkterm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`screen` can be used as a Terminal for serial ports - e.g. `screen /dev/ttyS0 19200`

Here are some more too - http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/5-linux-unix-commands-for-connecting-to-the-serial-console/

Answer (score 0):

You can use minicom, tip, cu on Linux (you may have to grab source for the last two). If you want a program to pull serial data, use python's 'serial' library. `pydoc serial` and `pydoc serial.Serial`.

You don't need to waste the Pi's onboard serial, you can use a USB serial-TTL cable. Costs a few dollars. Be careful with the serial voltage on your device, if it's higher than 5V you need another type of connection (or just a level shifter).